# Cucumber-java test steps execute twice in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber-jvm

Normally I run Cucumber-Jvm tests using Run/Debug configuration. Once I tried to run one tests using Run window by selecting the scenario (right click and run)
From that point on wards I see each time when I run test using Edit Configuration I see steps run twice.

I am using IntelliJ Community version

Anyone had this issue before could be any settings change.

Comment: Can you please provide sample project to reproduce? Is the issue reproduced with v2020.1 (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download)?

Comment: Yes I faced this issue initially, it was showing in logs (Intellij logs on the bottom left) as if tests were running twice but in actual the tests were running only once in Browser. 

Go to 'Edit Configuration' for your test and there you see 'Program arguments' edit box. Please make sure it's empty, if not do it. That worked for me.

Comment: @Python_Novice +1! It is not supposed to be empty, but mine had the JavaRunner twise in it. That's why it was showing that was running twice. Thanks, you helped me figure it out!

Answer (score 3):

*Right click* on the **Play button** on your `.feature` file and select the last choice *'Create Scenario ...'*. On the `Program arguments` box you should have `CucumberJvm5SMFormatter` only **ONCE**. I had:

```
--plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm5SMFormatter --plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm5SMFormatter --name "^My Scenario$"
```

Simply, I **deleted** the second line:

```
--plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm5SMFormatter --name "^My Scenario$"
```

and it ran perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Also depends on number of examples you have provided in cucumber

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31819999)

Answer (score 0):

You have probably another test with the same name